# Fit Iframe in div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, scroll

I have div (container) with height:100%; And I have an Iframe inside this div with also height:100%; Now the entire Iframe page is visible in the div.

The problem however is that the iframe is a long page which has scrolling. I don't want the scrolling to be visible at all, I want the native window scroll only.

As you can see in the [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8LrZq/)

to make the website visible I would have to force scrolling="yes" for the iframe. What can I do to avoid this and only use the body(page) scroll?

There are javascripts who can fix this, but a secondary problem is that I'm loading the iframe dynamicly, so not on page load.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Mashable as an example. In reality I do have control over the iframe document.

Comment: Is there a particular browser you are looking at this in?

Comment: @Sam I'm looking at it in Chrome, but of course it should work in all (popular) browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a play around with your code, i think its due to some margin or padding that causing the extra scroll. If you use fixed size div and iframe it works as you want (I think).

Take a look at the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8LrZq/1/).

The only changes were to your CSS, changing the height of div and iframe to 300px.

Comment: The problem is that the page is not visible...(I think you misunderstood the question)

Comment: @Youss Perhaps I did, let me reread and see if I misunderstood anything

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your DIV tag and putting this code on the page too:

```
html, body {
 height:100%;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How about adding overflow-x:hidden; and overflow-y:hidden; to the iFrame CSS.

Comment: I think the main problem is that Im loading dynamicly...css approach wont work